# A double recursive function (ping-pong) between function to itself complexity analysis

Tags: time-complexity

```
def RecFunc(n):
   if n <= 3:
      return 1

   return RecFunc( RecFunc(n/3) + RecFunc(n/2) + RecFunc(n/2) )
```

How should I start if it is nested inside? I know how to solve it without the outer `RecFunc` (with a recursive tree I assume) - But here there is an outer `RecFunc` and I don't know what to do!

---

Thanks to Steven for noticing a mistake I made (Misread the question and made it so `RecFunc(4)` will not halt)

Comment: `RecFunc(3)` calls `RecFunc(3)`, so this code still doesn't halt.

Comment: @Steven Forgot to edit the base case again.. so sorry.. a dumb mistake by me, is it ok now? if it still doesnot halt for some value of $n$ I need to ignore them and calculate a strict $\Theta$ value of the running time complexity and space

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the outer `RecFunc` call is just a "decoy" thrown in there to make the exercise seem more complicate than it is.
Indeed, it is irrelevant as far as the **asymptotic** time complexity is concerned. This is because every call to `RecFunc` eventually returns $1$ (that's the only possible returned value, you can prove by induction that `RecFunc` eventually returns), and therefore the last (outer) call to `RecFunc` will just be `RecFun(3)`, which terminates in constant time. We can charge this constant time to the caller function.
Since the caller is going to spend $\Theta(1)$ time anyway, this doesn't change anything.

Then you want to analyze:

```
def RecFunc(n):
   if n <= 3:
      return 1

   return RecFunc(n/3) + RecFunc(n/2) + RecFunc(n/2)
```

Whose running time is described by the recurrence equation:
$$
T(n)=2T(n/2) + T(n/3) + \Theta(1),
$$

which can be solved using the [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). Let $p$ such that:
$
2 \cdot \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} = 1.
$
Clearly $p>0$. Then:
$$
\int_{u=1}^n \frac{1}{u^{p+1}} \mathrm{d}u =
\int_{u=1}^n {u^{-p-1}} \mathrm{d}u =
-\frac{1}{p} \cdot  \left| u^{-p} \right|_{u=1}^n 
= \frac{1}{p} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^p} \right)
= \Theta(1),
$$
and you have:
$T(n) = \Theta(n^p)$. An approximation of $p$ is $1.3646$.

The space complexity is clearly $\Theta(\log n)$ since this is the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, I will edit it. I am so sorry! (You can keep this answer because it is a good point) Thank you sir!

Comment: Isn't it $ 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} = 1 $ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It’s obvious that recfunc(n) + 1 if n <= 3, then if n <= 6, n <= 12 etc. So recfunc(n) = 1 for all b, so we can calculate it in O(1).